# Spring, Annotation for Creating Current Date in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

in my Spring Application using JPA Hibernate Annotions.

In that mysql Database have table and one column called `CreateDate`

This column value will be added when record is inserted.

So is their any annotation for creating current Date and time?

other wise in our Hibernate bean writing setter method in that add

```
    private Date currrent;
    public void setCurrent(Date current)
    {
      this.current = new Date();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Jelies mentioned is the correct approach. You simply instantiate the date object with

```
private Date currrent = new Date();
```

during object creation and then persist it.

To add on to that, its not safe to use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` for storing the date and time, if there is a chance of you comparing the field `current` with any java.util.Date objects as the saved field will be loaded as java.sql.Timestamp. The reason is mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

> Note: This type is a composite of a java.util.Date and a separate nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the java.util.Date component. The fractional seconds - the nanos - are separate. The Timestamp.equals(Object) method never returns true when passed a value of type java.util.Date because the nanos component of a date is unknown. As a result, the Timestamp.equals(Object) method is not symmetric with respect to the java.util.Date.equals(Object) method. Also, the hashcode method uses the underlying java.util.Date implementation and therefore does not include nanos in its computation.
>   Due to the differences between the Timestamp class and the java.util.Date class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date. The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

The work around is to use [TypeDef](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6216). This [post](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/02/hibernate-date-vs-timestamp/) discusses about the issue and the workaround. The code used there will be good enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:-

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "curr", length = 10)
public Date getCurrrent() {
    return this.currrent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve that is to initialize your field with the new Date():

```
private Date currrent = new Date();
```

IMHO, I don't recommend changing the behavior of the setter method, other developers will not expect that.

If you want this field to be filled immediately before the entity is persisted/updated, you can define a method with `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate` JPA annotations to populate `current` property then.